# "toggleClass()" not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The `.toggleClass()` method is only adding "class" to my selection, so when clicking all i get is:

```
<div id="toggle" class>
...
```

Instead of

```
<div id="toggle" class="on">
...
```

I've been trying to figure it out for like 2 hours, reading posts about the same issue, but doesn't seem to be the same case as mine even though the result is.

Javascript's first bit is just animating a loading screen and hiding it

```js
$(function() {
  $(".loader_gif_wrapper").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(".slider").animate({
      width: ["0%", "swing"]
    }, 2000, function() {
      // Animation complete.
      $(".loader_page_wrapper").hide();
      // FIN ANIMACIONES LOADING


      $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        //$("nav").toggle();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  top: 3rem;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#toggle .span {
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: solid 1px $tres;
} //#toggle.on{
//    border: solid 0px $tres;}
#toggle.on #one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(2px) translateY(4px);
}

#toggle.on #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on #three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(8px) translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">
  <div class="span" id="one">One</div>
  <div class="span" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="span" id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not try adding a default class to the #toggle.

Comment: Is your animation of `.loader_gif_wrapper` and `.slider` working? Otherwise you will probably never reach the toggle binding.

Comment: no need of mentioning sass, as it is not in sass format.

Comment: @eisbehr yes, the animation is working. if i put a console warning inside the callback it is displayed. it's the first thing i checkewd when i saw toggleClass wasnt working. in fact it was adding 'class', but not 'class="on"'

Comment: Ahh, yes. ;) Now I see. You're right, adding an attribute without any value can lead to such side-effects. Glad you solved the issue by yourself. And see, it has nothing to do with where you placed the binding ...

Comment: @eisbehr no, no, the problem inside the callback was that it was adding 'class' instead of 'class="on"'. when moved outside of callback it just worked as expected. still wondering why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the event declaration out of the callback so you will be sure that event will be attached in all case if the callback reached or not :

```
$(function() {
  $(".loader_gif_wrapper").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(".slider").animate({
      width: ["0%", "swing"]
    }, 2000, function() {
      // Animation complete.
      $(".loader_page_wrapper").hide();
    });
  });

  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    //$("nav").toggle();
  });
});
```

**WORKING SAMPLE**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  top: 2rem;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: green;
}

#toggle .span {
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: solid 1px;
  border: solid 0px;
}

#toggle.on #one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(2px) translateY(4px);
}

#toggle.on #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on #three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(8px) translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="toggle">
  <div class="span" id="one"></div>
  <div class="span" id="two"></div>
  <div class="span" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Belongs to what he want to do, or not? If he want to bind it after animation is finished, it would be correct ...

Comment: It isn't a good practice since the event will be redeclared every time the callback reached..

Comment: @eisbehr  without doing as Zakaria Acharki do it does not work (I check it out)

Comment: The callback can only be reached once. And as his animation takes three seconds to complete, it sometimes can make sense to wait for bindings. But that can only be answered by the OP. But still, this is not an "error".

Comment: yeah, it works putting the click event outside the animation callback. don't understand why it doesn't work insdide though.

Comment: Because something else is wrong with your code then. @TheBandolero

Comment: @eisbehr and if the callback isn't reached at all ?? who will attach the callback? and I guess that what happens in this case ... anyway attaching events inside loops and callbacks isn't a good practice.

Comment: If the callback isn't reached, the code has issues somewhere else. His code works in general. It could be an HTML issue or a race condition. But putting bindings in callbacks isn't basically _bad_.  This belongs to the usecase and what he want to do. But without any more detailed information, your answer doesn't help anything. Yes, it's working now, but possible only because you didn't find the real issue and just bypassed the initial problem ...